# Overwrite Capitalize with default behavior?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

I'm working on a Wordpress site using the Thesis theme. Say I have a menu item, "Foo is Bar" By default, the navigation in Thesis is styled with:

```
text-transform: uppercase;//FOO IS BAR
```

which is overwritten in my custom style-sheet to:

```
text-transform: capitalize;//Foo Is Bar
```

Which is close, but what I want, is the menu item to be rendered as "Foo is Bar" as written with mixed upper and lower case starting letters.  The uppercase style is part of the Theme and I'd rather not modify the code if I don't have to.  Is there a way to wipe out the uppercase style perhaps using the :first-letter pseudo class?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set it back to the default:

```
text-transform: none;
```